# Displaying and clearing values in label from database

Tags: mysql, vb.net, mysql-workbench

**Hello**

I have a datatable called `Customer` with the attributes `CustomerID`, `Firstname` and `Surname`.

So far I have managed to display the labels with the correct customer connected to the correct customerID. As I write the CustomerID, it displays the firstname and the surname of the customer in the lables.

For example, If I write 5022(is a customerID) in the textbox, then `lblFirstname = Jon` and `lblSurname = Snow`. However, if I continue to write, say 502222, then it will still display Jon Snow. I want to make it appear only if it's exactly right, meaning that the labels will clear if I write a customerID that doesn't exists.

Here is my code so far:

```
       Dim customerID As Integer

    If txtCustomer.Text <> "" Then
        CustomerID = CInt(txtCustomer.Text)
        myCommand.CommandText = "Select firstname, surname from customer where CustomerID = " & CustomerID & ""
        myAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(myCommand)
        myTable = New DataTable
        myAdapter.Fill(myTable)



        If myTable.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            lblFirstname.Text = myTable.Rows(0)("Firstname").ToString()
            lblSurname.Text = myTable.Rows(0)("Surname").ToString()
        End If

    Else
        lblFirstname.Text = ""
        lblSurname.Text = ""
    End If
    myConnection.Close()
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you have a problem with adding text to the labels.. Have you somewhere in your code assigned variables to your labels. If you have, remove them, I think that'll do the trick.